# API level mismatch in ionic cordova to get APK

Tags: android, api, ionic-framework, apk, ionic4

I have Created the android application using ionic and angularjs.when i try to build and get apk following error appers.[!{this is the error}](https://i.stack.imgur.com/98tZE.jpg)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/98tZE.jpg). to resolve this error i have done some changes

1.in config file i change the minsdk and trget sdk values to api level 23

2.in gradle.build file change the sdkversion to api level 23.

but nothing changes.i need to get apk for apilevel 23(MAshmillow).

how to solve this error..?[image: here is the gradel that i changed]
[image: Here is the config file that i changed.]

Answer (score 0):

Find the sql path and execute the following
[image]

`./sdkmanager.bat --licenses`

After this you can review each license and accept them accordingly.

Edit: To add api version do the following:

```
<preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="23" />
```

Comment: i need to change api level 28 to api level 23. how should i do that..?@Athif Shaffy

Comment: Updated answer, with latest